# Get spring boot pagination number starts from 1 instead of 0

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination

I am using spring boot for my API. There is a concept of pagination in my API so I am using spring-data-core 2.5.5 RELEASE for this. Now in response when I access the first page of my API the pagable object in the Response is as following

`"page": {
        "size": 200,
        "totalElements": 15,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 1 // always less than by 1 from the given page number
    }`

I have already tried setting the property **setOneIndexedParameters(true)**
but the issue still persists.

Please tell me a way to get it right without increasing the number in code.

Answer (score 6):

How did you set the property `setOneIndexedParameters`? To customize the pagination you just need to register a bean implementing the interface `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`.

**For example**

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig {

    @Bean
    public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer customize() {
        return p -> p.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
@Component
public class CustomConfig implements 
                    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pr) {
        pr.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
    }
}
```

Ref: [HandlerMethodArgumentResolvers for Pageable and Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#core.web.basic.paging-and-sorting)